# Azure app service deployment fails at core-js postinstall

Tags: deployment, azure-web-app-service, core-js

I am deploying a teams app using custom deployment template and a git repo url. The deployment was successfull previously and from last week deployment is failing at core-js postinstall. Below is the log for the same.

[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AADaF.png)

Please let me know what I am missing and why only at core-js it fails?

log:  > core-js@3.22.7 postinstall C:\home\site\repository\Source\Microsoft.Teams.Apps.SubmitIdea\ClientApp\node_modules\core-js

> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
> Command 'starter.cmd "C:\home\site\d ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 60 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.\r\nstarter.cmd "C:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Could you please specify the source which you are following to achieve this ?

Comment: Deployment guide: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-greatideas/wiki/Deployment-guide and the same code from same repo

Comment: In  Azure portal =>Your  App Service =>Configuration => Application settings tab  ,  Create a key `WEBSITE_IDLE_TIMEOUT` with value 3600 under App settings section

Comment: That is not useful since when we start deplyment it expects that Azure resorce group to be empty and at run time, all the resources gets added to this. after which, npm install will run and it will start adding project dependencies and at this point it fails..!!

Comment: @Shashidhar running into a similar error while deploying a NodeJS web app that just mysteriously started happening on May 18 for us. Were you able to find a solution or workaround? Thank you in advance.

Comment: DaveG-W: working with right node version only will fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My deployment issue got fixed when I changed Default node version to ~16 instead of 16.15.0 in deployment template. Azure supports 16.13.0 as of now.

Comment: I was running into a similar issue, and can confirm that setting the default node version to 16 seems to have resolved the issue. I was previously on node v14.18. Everything deployed fine at the end of May. It's really frustrating not knowing why it started failing, or why changing node versions fixed it :/